# How to implement xml namespace throgh spring annotation

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to implement `spring-data-mongo` and i am defining my beans through `@configuration` and `@bean` (not through `xml` file).

Now i need following namespace included in order to get the `mongoTemplate`.

```
xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
```

in my bean configuration.

I can still use `xml` configuration and load it in my application context but i was just wondering if namespace can be implemented through spring annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add @EnableMongoRepositories to your configuration class.

Source: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.7.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#mongo.repositories